# Wrap elements inside a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, word-wrap

I have this:

```
<div>content element</div>
<div class="accordionTrigger">
  <div><h1>title</h1></div>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  ...
</div>
<div>content element</div>
<div>content element</div>
```

I need to wrap all the p-tags inside a div like this:

```
    <div>content element</div>
    <div class="accordionTrigger">
      <div><h1>title</h1></div>
      <div class="moreInfo">    
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>content element</div>
    <div>content element</div>
```

can it be done with jQuery?

---

If I have more than one `<div class="accordionTrigger"></div>`, like this:

```
<div>content element</div>
<div class="accordionTrigger">
  <div><h1>title</h1></div>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  ...
</div>
<div>content element</div>
<div class="accordionTrigger">
  <div><h1>title</h1></div>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  ...
</div>
```

the result will be:

```
<div>content element</div>
<div class="accordionTrigger">
  <div><h1>title</h1></div>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  ...
</div>
<div>content element</div>
<div class="accordionTrigger">
  <div><h1>title</h1></div>
</div>
```

can I avoid that?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Check the [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) method:

```
$('.accordionTrigger p').wrapAll('<div class="moreInfo"></div>');
```

The wrapAll() method will wrap all the elements matched into another element (compared to the .wrap() method which wraps the matched elements individually)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/vwmHF/)**

Comment: Is there any danger or gotcha's from using this function? Will this destroy and recreate this part of the DOM? Will it nuke any event handlers or what not on the previous elements?

Comment: As far as I know it won't touch the elements to wrap, just move them as children of the wrapping element. You can see the source of the function here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/main/src/wrap.js. Now concerning events, it also depends on how you bind them (directly or using delegation..).

Answer (score 2):

**Check this it will work out as per expectation**

```
<div>content element</div>
<div class="accordionTrigger">
  <div><h1>title</h1></div>


  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $("p").wrapAll("<div class='moreinfo'/>"); 
  </script>
</div>
<div>content element</div>
<div>content element</div>
```