# PHP - wrap an image with a span tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Hi I am trying to wrap images containing a specific class (pinthis is this example) in a span to which I will add info for schema. This is a basic example and I will need to inject other schema info also. To get me started though can anyone help me get from my existing code to my example output. I need to update multiple pages dynamically and some of the content will come via PHP from Wordpress taxonomies and other data so would prefer to do it in PHP if possible.

```
<p>
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="image.jpg">
<img src="img.jpg" alt="alt text" width="1000" height="1000" class="various classes including ... pinthis">
</a>
</p>
```

Which I would like to become...

```
<p>
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="image.jpg">
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
<img src="img.jpg" alt="alt text" width="1000" height="1000" class="various classes including ... pinthis">
</span>
</a>
</p>
```

I think if someone could point me in the right direction and give me a push start that would give me enough to carry on from there

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have a function or code that outputs the whole piece of HTML you gave?

Comment: You need the code that will parse existing HTML output and modify it or you need to modify the function that makes this output?

Comment: Thank you - no that's my problem. These are all Wordpress posts individually written. The one common element that I can see that I can use to identify the images I want to wrap with the schema info is that they contain the 'pinthis' class which is a class I add manually and relates to a third party plugin. My only other option I can see is to edit all the posts manually but that would be quite a few.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP DOMDocument, you could do something like this:

```
$html = '<p><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="image.jpg"><img src="img.jpg" alt="alt text" width="1000" height="1000" class="various classes pinthis"></a></p>';

// Create a DOMDocument and load the HTML.
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

// Create the span wrapper.
$span = $dom->createElement('span');
$span->setAttribute('itemscope', '');
$span->setAttribute('itemtype', 'http://schema.org/ImageObject');

// Get all the images. 
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

// Loop the images.
foreach ($images as $image) {

    // Only affect those with the pinthis class.
    if (strpos($image->getAttribute('class'), 'pinthis') !== false) {

        // Clone the span if we need to use it often.
        $span_clone = $span->cloneNode();

        // Replace the image tag with the span tag.
        $image->parentNode->replaceChild($span_clone, $image);

        // Add the image tag as a child of the new span tag.
        $span_clone->appendChild($image);
    }
}

// Get your HTML with saveHTML()
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $html;
```

Just modify the code to suit your specific needs. For example, if you need to change your span tag attributes, if you are changing your class for searching, etc... You might even want to make a function where you can specify your class and span attributes.

Documentation to DOMDocument: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Thank you, this looks interesting. The line I'm note sure of is `$html = '<p><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="image.jpg"><img src="img.jpg" alt="alt text" width="1000" height="1000" class="various classes pinthis"></a></p>';` how does that become universal (for example image href, source, classes and alt text will definitely vary). The structure should always be the same and the `pinthis` class will always be present.

Comment: The code isolates img tags with the pinthis class, then adds a span wrapper around them. It does not modify the rest of the HTML which can be anything.

Comment: Thank you Pierre so the `$html =` top line is required but could really say anything?

Comment: Yes, it's whatever HTML you want to modify. I put it there for the example. I have no idea how you are getting the HTML you want to work on, so you'll have to figure that part out.

Comment: Ah well in that case I suspect something like `$html = get_the_content();` would retrieve the entire post and then the rest of the code would get to work on it. I'll research that a little more. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use [**warpAll**](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)

- check if the `image` has required `class`
- if image has class, then `wrap` it with the desired `<span></span>`

Try it this way :

```
if ($('img.classes').hasClass('pinthis')){
       $('img.classes').wrapAll('<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">></span>');
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pj5c1r4a/)

helpful thread : **[jquery, wrap elements inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291723/jquery-wrap-elements-inside-a-div)**

Comment: this won't help for the seo purposes. js will be rendered after page load so robots won't see the tag.

Comment: @artuc : `I need to update multiple pages dynamically` - you have a better solution for that?? i dont see how PHP would be able to do it on dynamic level plus where is SEO mentioned?

Comment: This is not a solution, you're adding micro format data for seo purposes which will help you to have a better seo ranking. Adding / removing dom elements in javascript will not have any effect for the solution. This is why this answer is useless.

Comment: @artuc : ok...i am eager to see how PHP solves this problem....but as per my knowledge, combined with PHP, dynamic stuff will still have to use some form of jQuery, besides, *inject* ing `span` in an existing DOM  *WILL* need jQuery....don't you think??:)