# image popup in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need to give popup  for all the images displayed under a div
i tried to  add div before and after image tag but its not appending properly

this is my following code

```
<div class="description">
<img alt="" src="image.jpg" style="height:350px; width:700px" id="imagepopup0"></div>
```

Expected output

```
<div class="description">
<div class="fancybox"> //class to be added

<img alt="" src="image.jpg" style="height:350px; width:700px" id="imagepopup0">
</div> // div to be added
</div>
```

Comment: post your js code also

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9291723/5283213

Comment: $('.description').children().wrap('<div class="fancybox">');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some JQuery for this, but you have to change the html code a bit.

See snippet

```js
$('.imagepopup0').click(function() {
  $('.outer').toggle('show');
  $('.fancybox').toggle('show');
});
```

```css
/* Not needed, just for show */
.fancybox {
  background-color: blue;
}
.description {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="description">
  <img src="http://www.jamfoo.com/chat/smiley.png" class="imagepopup0 outer">
  <div class="fancybox" style="display: none;">
    <img src="http://www.jamfoo.com/chat/smiley.png" class="imagepopup0">
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8qg5y5d/1/)

Comment: I keep clicking your snippet... Anyway should I care about additional image tag? While `src` will stay the same in and outside, indeed browser will not try to load it twice, but I feel kinda bad when it comes to repeat exact same img tag.

Comment: @NightKn8 Don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Original answer: [jquery, wrap elements inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9291760/5283213)

Could use the [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) method:

```
$('#imagepopup0').wrapAll('<div class="fancybox"></div>');
```

The `wrapAll()` method will wrap all the elements matched into another element whereas the `.wrap()` method which wraps the matched elements individually.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion friends i have found a simple solution for that instead of using div i user a tag and fancy box in it 
the following code working fine for me

```
$("#imgid").wrap('<a class ="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="'+srcimg+'" />');

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // FANCYBOX JS
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        // openEffect: "none",
        // closeEffect: "none"
    });
});
 </script>
```