# Create new div and insert exisintg elements

Tags: jquery, html

At the moment I have something like this:

```
  <body>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
  </body>
```

I need to create with jquery a new `<div class="four">` which would contain two existing divs.

The final result should be:

```
  <body>
    <div class="four">
      <div class="one"></div>
      <div class="two></div>
    </div>
    <div class="three"></div>
  </div>
```

I tried a few functions but I can't get it right. Thanks!

Comment: [`.wrapAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/): _"Wrap an HTML structure around all elements in the set of matched elements."_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery, wrap elements inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291723/jquery-wrap-elements-inside-a-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did and it worked, thanks for your suggestions:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".one, .two").wrapAll("<div class='four'></div>");
  })
```

```css
.four {
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="one">1</div>
    <div class="two">2</div>
    <div class="three">3</div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select the child elemnets and use the [wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) jQuery function to create the parent element.

Here's an example:

```js
$('.child').wrapAll("<div class='four' />");
```

```css
.four {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="child one">One</div>
  <div class="child two">Two</div>
  <div class="child three">Three</div>
</body>
```